# Puppet Agent still able to connect to Master after certificate revocation

Tags: puppet

In summary:

- Client connects for the first time and requests cert;
- on the Master, `puppetca -s client` is executed;
- Client gets the cert and completes the run successfully.

Fine. But now:

- on the Master, `puppetca -c client` is executed and client's cert is not in the cert list anymore;
- Client connects again and can perform the run as usual;

Restarting puppetmasterd doesn't solve the issue.
How can I prevent client to connect once its cert has been revoked?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the message given by `puppetca -c client`? How do you tell that the client's cert is not in the cert list? What is your OS and Puppet version? How do you run the puppet master? How many clients do you have?

Comment: (1) I don't have a new client to try the `-c`, but it's the usual success message. (2) `-l` lists the certs and it's not there anymore.  (3) Ubuntu 10.04, puppet 2.7.9 (4) Do you mean `service puppetmaster start`? (5) 12 clients

Comment: How do you run puppet on the client? `puppetd --test`? Does `puppetd --test` run properly? Do the master's log files just show a normal connection and run by the client?

Comment: (1) `puppetd --onetime --no-daemonize --verbose --waitforcert 5` (2) `--test` runs properly, even when the cert has been revoked (3) Unfortunately I've never been able to enable logging on the master...

Comment: Do you have `autosign` enabled by any chance? `/etc/puppet/autosign.conf` on your puppetmaster should be either empty or non-existent.

Comment: No, the file doesn't even exist.

Comment: Are you using apache passenger or the default WEBrick server with puppetmaster?

Comment: Apache was on the server before installing puppetmaster, but I haven't modified the puppetmaster installation by any means.  I frankly don't know what to answer. Can I check this somehow?

Comment: You can run "sudo lsof | grep LISTEN  | grep 8140".  This will show you which process is listening on the puppet master port.  If you find that apache is the process in the leftmost column, you'd likely need to restart apache rather than puppetmaster to re-read the certificate revocation list.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is to verify that the cert is actually revoked from the CA. Fire the following command to check that:

```
puppetca --list --all
```

If you are sure that the cert was revoked then ensure that auto-signing is off. Not only the autosign file, check the puppet.conf also. You have to disable it. If you think that your infra will be impacted by turning it off then simply use auth.conf to block the particular host in question.

Hope it helped.